# Sitecore 7 Content Search indexing items outside of crawler root

Tags: lucene, sitecore, sitecore7

I've created a custom content search index in Sitecore v7.1.

The indexing and crawling works fine, and I am able to search the index and return items correctly. The issue I am having is that the index sometimes gets populated with items that are outside of the "crawling root" value (see configuration below.

The work around so far has been to add template excludes to the `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config` but this is annoying as I have lots of non-content templates that I don't want to have to continue to add to this file.

My index configuration is as follows (This is in a config include file):

```xml
    <configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <contentSearch>
            <configuration type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneSearchConfiguration, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
                    <index id="artscentre_web_index" type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.SwitchOnRebuildLuceneIndex, Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider">
                        <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
                        <param desc="folder">$(id)</param>
                        <!-- This initializes index property store. Id has to be set to the index id -->
                        <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />
                        <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
                            <!-- NOTE: order of these is controls the execution order -->
                            <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexUpdateStrategies/onPublishEndAsync" />
                        </strategies>
                        <commitPolicyExecutor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.CommitPolicyExecutor, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                            <policies hint="list:AddCommitPolicy">
                                <policy type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.TimeIntervalCommitPolicy, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
                            </policies>
                        </commitPolicyExecutor>
                        <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
                            <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                                <Database>web</Database>
                                <Root>/sitecore/content/Sites/ArtsCentre/Home</Root>
                            </crawler>
                        </locations>
                    </index>
                </indexes>
            </configuration>
        </contentSearch>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

As you can see, my crawler root tag should mean the index only indexes my content items, yet it's indexing items from places such as `/sitecore/content/Sites/SiteA/Configuration`

Any help on this would be great :)

Cheers, 
Justin

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug in sitecore! It is reported, but no estimation on when it will be fixed.

The bug is in the `Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler.IsAncestorOf` method, where it doesn't do the right check.

This is the advice i got from sitecore support:

> For the meantime, we suggest you implement the following workaround to
>   resolve the issue:
>
> 1. Create a class derived from the `Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler` class.
> 2. Override its IsAncestorOf method. The new method should look as follows:
>
>    ```
>     protected override bool IsAncestorOf(Item item)
>     {
>       bool result;
>       using (new SecurityDisabler())
>       {
>         using (new CachesDisabler())
>         {
>           //result = item.Axes.IsAncestorOf(item);
>           result = this.RootItem.Axes.IsAncestorOf(item);
>         }
>       }
>       return result;
>     }
>    ```
> 3. Build the class into an assembly. Place the assembly to the site's bin folder.
> 4. Comment out all occurrences of the SitecoreItemCrawler class in your configuration. Insert new crawler definitions to use new crawler.
>      By default you need to modify the following config files:
>
>    ```
>     Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.Index.Core.config
>     Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.Index.Master.config
>     Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.Index.Web.config
>
>     <!--<crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">-->
>     <crawler type="[fully qualified class name], [your assembly name]">
>    ```
> 5. Rebuild the indexes.

Comment: Small note: Doing a full rebuild of the index, will clear the index and only put in the documents allowed (because it will start at the document root). Each time you publish stuff, it will be put in the index if it passes the other checks (template include/exclude), because of the bug!

Comment: Thanks for providing that fix, I'll look to implement that and see how I go. With it passing the other checks and being added to the index, will the fix above prevent that from happening, but I suspect that is what is happening, as a full rebuild of the index removes the items that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Works fine except for the CachesDisabler(). What do I need to reference in order to use it?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but seems like the CachesDisabler is an internal class in the Sitecore.ContentSearch.dll file. But you should be able to use "Sitecore.Data.DatabaseCacheDisabler". The CachesDisabler is just a wrapper for the DatabaseCacheDisabler. I'll update the answer with this code

Comment: Note to say this is fixed on v 7.2 and also that `CachesDisabler()` is misleading as it only disables the caches IF the setting is configured in `Sitecore.ContentSearch.config` under the settings `<setting name="ContentSearch.Indexing.DisableDatabaseCaches" value="true"/>`